# JHipster backend - Social login

Tags: java, spring, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, jhipster

I created a spring backend using JHipster backend and now it's time to build the social login. I implement the login logic on the clientside, but I want to store the users on the backend as well. JHipster provides this route:

```
@GetMapping("/signup")
public RedirectView signUp(WebRequest webRequest, @CookieValue(name = "NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY", required = false, defaultValue = "\"en\"") String langKey) {
    try {
        Connection<?> connection = providerSignInUtils.getConnectionFromSession(webRequest);
        socialService.createSocialUser(connection, langKey.replace("\"", ""));
        return new RedirectView(URIBuilder.fromUri("http:localhost:4200/social-register/" + connection.getKey().getProviderId())
            .queryParam("success", "true")
            .build().toString(), true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception creating social user: ", e);
        return new RedirectView(URIBuilder.fromUri("/#/social-register/no-provider")
            .queryParam("success", "false")
            .build().toString(), true);
    }
}
```

What is this Connection about and what should the input to this request be, in order to store my logged in user from e.g. Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

What is the authentication that you choose while creating the project?

If you select Social Login while creating the project, then Social login is already implemented, all you need to do is create your facebook app id and update it into the jhipster project.

Comment: I'm using the microservices flow, which doesn't support social login out of the box.